# Creating custom Actions within an Retention Policy 

Tags: 2007, information-management, custom-actions

Does anyone know, either via the object model or through xml, if you can create custom actions for a retention policy, which is defined as part of an Information Management Policy?

I know that you can create custom retention formulas but am unsure about custom actions. Has anyone ever done this?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Microsoft has hard coded javascript in that defines the options...bit of a shame really as I think that it could have had real value.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you can create a custom action as mentioned in:

http://zieglers.wordpress.com/2010/01/18/custom-document-expiration-policy-part-3-additions/

Alternatively, you can set the action to start a specific workflow.