# Does adding custom code to native SharePoint aspx files automatically result in an unsupported state?

Tags: 2010, 2013, development

I want to add some custom code to one of the native SharePoint's aspx files in the hive (14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS). Specifically, I wish to implement a `Page_LoadComplete` event that does some additional processing after the aspx has already been loaded.

Would any such modification automatically result in an unsupported state, regardless of the code added, and should as such be avoided?

Comment: What people usually do, I think, is to use and IHTTPModule or something to redirect requests from that page to a custom page.

Comment: @CameronVerhelst yes, that's the alternative I was actually thinking about, although redirection is not what I'm after.

Comment: Which page do you want to change ?

Comment: @CameronVerhelst - it's related to this question: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/108333/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-hide-specific-custom-retention-actions-in-the-drop

Comment: The related question is to do with custom retention policies, it's not a page that would get "much" use I think, so redirecting to a custom page should not incur a big performance hit. If you can just copy paste the existing aspx content and map it to the same code behind, you should be free to make your own changes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, being a straight modification on a default SharePoint file, it will bring your farm to an unsupported state